# how to calculate this euler equation or e of P(X)?

Tags: probability, exponential-function, exponential-distribution, euler-mascheroni-constant

I cannot understand how the below equation produce this result?
Can anyone please explain the steps for this calculation? I tried finding the exponential values but it gives 2.36*10-06

> What is our estimated probability of $\color{red}{\text{default}}$ for someone with a balance of $\$1000$? $$\hat p(X)=\dfrac{e^{\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1X}}{1+e^{\hat\beta_0+\hat\beta_1X}}=\dfrac{e^{-10.6513+0.0055\times 1000}}{1+e^{-10.6513+0.0055\times 1000}}\approx 0.006$$

Comment: It's better if you write out the math, instead of making people go off to another website to see it. There is help available for formatting mathematics here.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where your calculation error lies, but

$−10.6513+0.0055×1000 = -5.1513
\\[3ex]e^{-5.1513}\approx0.00579187039907138388429878810264\\[3ex]\dfrac{0.00579187039907138388429878810264}{1+0.00579187039907138388429878810264}\approx0.00575851781022382315801616604296$